# Question about action-reaction pair of two wires carrying current in the same direction

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Imagine two wires lined up so that they are parallel, and that they both have a current running through them in the same direction.  The magnetic field produced by the current of one of the wires (say, the left wire) interacts with the current of the right wire, and induces a force on the right wire towards the left wire.  Now, looking at this from the point of view from Newton's third law, the left wire would also have a force accelerating it in the direction towards the right wire.  Would this action reaction pair be the result of the right wire's magnetic field produced from its current?  If not, does that mean the right wire produces another second force, resulting in a second action reaction pair, for a total of 4 forces in the system?  Or is the action reaction pair already the result of both wires creating a magnetic field, and both wires having a current, giving only 2 forces in the system total?

Comment: you could ask the same question using gravity instead of wires, what is the answer in such a case?